# What is the difference between print and formatted string literals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format-string

What is the point of using code, like on line 8 and 9, when we can use `print` like on line 10?

```
my_name = 'Zed A. Shaw'
my_age = 35
my_height = 74
my_weight = 180
my_eyes = 'Blue'
my_teeth = 'White'
my_hair = 'Brown'
print(f"Let's talk about {my_name}.") # Line 8
print(f"He's {my_height} inches tall.") # Line 9
print("He's", my_teeth, "pounds heavy.") # Line 10
```

Comment: And the previous 2 lines are examples of String Interpolation. It's very handy, but this example is too petty for the benefits to be obvious.

Comment: @Astolfo39 2 other notes when posting code here: 1. don't include the line numbers on the left; it makes it more difficult for people to run your code. If you need to indicate a line number, use a comment. 2. Indent code by 4 spaces to format it properly. See the fixed up code I posted.

Comment: String formatting is rather powerful for non-trivial cases, see some uses at https://pyformat.info/ , but note you're using f-strings here, which are specific to Python 3.6 currently

Comment: @Carcigenicate I need to indent when writing codes or just for websites? When I use indentations in notepads the terminal says unexpected indentations. The author of this book I am reading now also indents so I am really confused when there is an unexpected indentation error. Everything is alright if I deleted all the indentations.

Comment: @Astolfo39 No, indent when posting code here. When you indent code by four spaces, the site formats your code nicely. You can also highlight the code and press ctrl+k. Press edit under your question. Note I just added four spaces in the front of each line.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing on lines 8-9 are called *formatted string literals* or *f-strings* for short. They were added to Python in version 3.6, and detailed in [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). They basically allow you to embed expressions directly in strings.

> What['s] the point of using line 8 and line 9 if we can just use line 10?

So, what *is* the point of using them over the normal call to `print`? In the example above, not much. The real benefit is shown when you need to format strings using multiple values. Rather than doing doing a bunch of string concatenation, you can directly use the name of a variable or include an expression in the string:

```
>>> a = 12
>>> b = 6
>>> f'The sum of 12 and 6 is: {a + b}'
'The sum of 12 and 6 is: 18'
>>> name = 'Bob'
>>> age = 32
>>> f'Hi. My name is {name} and my age is {age}'
'Hi. My name is Bob and my age is 32'
>>> def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

>>> f'The Fibonacci number of 10 is: {fib(10)}'
'The Fibonacci number of 10 is: 89'
```

Although is may be hard to tell from the above examples, *f-strings are very powerful*. Being able to embed entire expressions inside of a string literal is a very useful feature, and can also make for more clear and concise code. This will be become very clear when you begin to write more code and the use cases for your code becomes non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

In short, they allow you to format your strings. If you need formatting then (for example)

`print(f"hello {world}")`

returns

hello **world**